# SQL Server Output : How should i proceed to get this output in Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is sample data against which I want to write a query

```
Shopkeeper |       Date    |    Product
----------------------------------------
SA10000601 |    2011-12-01 |    8183
SA10000601 |    2011-02-01 |    190
SA10000601 |    2011-04-01 |    3192
SA10000601 |    2011-03-01 |    4195
SA10000601 |    2011-04-01 |    9195
SA10000605 |    2011-12-01 |    8183
SA10000601 |    2011-02-01 |    190
JA10000607 |    2011-04-01 |    3192
SA10000604 |    2011-03-01 |   195
JA10000603 |    2011-04-01 |    9195
SA10000601 |    2011-12-01 |    8183
SA10000601 |    2011-02-01 |    190
SA10000601 |    2011-04-01 |    3192
SA10000601 |    2011-09-01 |    4195
SA10000601 |    2011-08-01 |    9195
SA10000904 |    2011-08-01 |    9195
SA10000601 |    2011-05-01 |    8180
SA10000606 |    2011-03-01 |    190
SA10000601 |    2011-08-01 |   3192
SA10000609 |    2011-11-01 |    4195
```

I want to display all the products which have been sold only for 1 month, sold for 2-3 months in year, sold for 4-5 months in year, sold for 6-7 months in an year.

In the same table, I want to display shopkeepers who have been selling only for one month, shopkeepers who have been selling for 2-3 months, who have been selling for 4-5 months.

Should somewhat look like this (sample output):

```
Months     | Shopkeepers     |    Product sold
-----------------------------------------------
1 month    |       5         |        10
2-3 months |       3         |        2 
4-5 months |       8         |        4
```

How should the query go in SQL Server? Please seek more explanations, as I have to resolve this today. Thanks in advance :)

P.S.: Apologies for those tables, how to put data in tables here?

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: I am trying to use Case statement , but not successful at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.MonthCount AS Months, COUNT(t2.Shopkeeper) AS Shopkeepers,
    SUM(t1.ProductCount) AS `Product Sold`
FROM
(
    SELECT Shopkeeper, COUNT(DISTINCT Product) AS ProductCount
    FROM products
    GROUP BY Shopkeeper
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Shopkeeper, COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(Date)) AS MonthCount
    FROM products
    GROUP BY Shopkeeper
) t2
ON t1.Shopkeeper = t2.Shopkeeper
GROUP BY t2.MonthCount
```

Here is the output from your sample data above:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ MonthCount ║ Shopkeepers ║ Product Sold ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║     1      ║      7      ║      7       ║
║     7      ║      1      ║      6       ║  
╚════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Note that in your sample data above, there are only 2 types of shopkeepers: those who have sold in one month only (7 of them), and one who sold in 7 months.  I chose to leave out the groupings by month, but it would not be too difficult to add this functionality yourself.

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88704/7)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @table table
(shop_keeper nvarchar(50),[date]  date,product_sold int)

insert into @table
select 'SA10000601',     '2011-12-01',     8183
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-01-01',     10
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-02-01',     190
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-04-01',     3192
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-03-01',     4195
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-04-01',     9195
union all select 'SA10000605',     '2011-12-01',     8183
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-02-01',     190
union all select 'JA10000607',     '2011-04-01',     3192
union all select 'SA10000604',     '2011-03-01',    195
union all select 'JA10000603',     '2011-04-01',     9195
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-12-01',     8183
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-02-01',     190
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-04-01',     3192
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-09-01',     4195
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-08-01',     9195
union all select 'SA10000904',     '2011-08-01',     9195
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-05-01',     8180
union all select 'SA10000606',     '2011-03-01',     190
union all select 'SA10000601',     '2011-08-01',    3192
union all select 'SA10000609',     '2011-11-01',     4195


WITH cte
    AS (
        SELECT month([date]) AS [month]
            ,sum([product_sold]) AS [product_sold]
            ,count(shop_keeper) AS shop_keeper
            ,CASE 
                WHEN month([date]) % 2 = 0
                    THEN month([date])
                ELSE month([date]) - 1
                END AS RN
        FROM @table
        GROUP BY month([date])
        )
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN RN <> 0
                AND RN <> 12
                THEN cast(RN AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + cast(RN + 1 AS VARCHAR) + ' Months'
            WHEN Rn = 0
                THEN cast(RN + 1 AS VARCHAR) + ' Month'
            ELSE cast(RN AS VARCHAR) + ' Months'
            END AS [months]
        ,sum(product_sold) product_sold
        ,sum(shop_keeper) shop_keeper
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY RN
```

Output

```
+----------------+--------------+-------------+
|     months     | product_sold | shop_keeper |
+----------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1 Month        |           10 |           1 |
| 2 - 3 Months   |         5150 |           6 |
| 4 - 5 Months   |        36146 |           6 |
| 8 - 9 Months   |        25777 |           4 |
| 10 - 11 Months |         4195 |           1 |
| 12 Months      |        24549 |           3 |
+----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT month(date) AS month, count(shopkeepers) AS shopkeepers, sum(productsold) AS productsold
FROM products
GROUP BY month(date)
```